# Let f be a differentiable function from $R$ into $R$ with simple zeros, then what is the cardinality of the set consisting of zeros of f?

Tags: real-analysis

e.g. f(x)= sinx, then it satisfies the conditions of the problem, so it is natural to expect that the Lebesgue measure of the set of zeros of $f$ will be zero. But, I am not able to prove it in general.

Comment: What do you mean by "simple" zero? Isn't $f(x)=0$ a counterexample?

Comment: I would guess he means that $f(x)=0$ but $f'(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: You can show that there are countable many simple zeros. If there were uncountably many, then there exists a closed interval $[a,b]$ that also has uncountably many zeros, which implies that there is some point $c\in[a,b]$ such that every neighborhood of $c$ contains uncountably many zeros. You can use the fact that the zeros are simple to make this a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $x \neq 0$, and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ such that $f(x) = 0$, and $f(x_n)=0$ for each $n$. Then you have 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x)-f(x_n)}{x-x_n} = 0$$

This shows you that the set of simple zeros has all its points isolated. So it has Lebesgue mesure equal to $0$.

Comment: Actually the zero set is at most countable, a stronger result.